# Extract the first 2 Characters in a string

Tags: r, substr

I need to extract the 1st 2 characters in a string to later create bin plot distribution. 
vector:

```
x <- c("75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85 to 89")
```

I have gotten this far:

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n, nchar(x))
}
```

invoke function

```
substrRight(x, 1)
```

Response

```
[1] "79" "84" "89"
```

Need to prints the last 2 characters not the first.

```
[1] "75" "80" "85"
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can just use the `substr` function directly to take the first two characters of each string:

```
x <- c("75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85 to 89")
substr(x, start = 1, stop = 2)
# [1] "75" "80" "85"
```

You could also write a simple function to do a "reverse" substring, giving the 'start' and 'stop' values assuming the index begins at the end of the string:

```
revSubstr <- function(x, start, stop) {
  x <- strsplit(x, "")
  sapply(x, 
         function(x) paste(rev(rev(x)[start:stop]), collapse = ""), 
         USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}
revSubstr(x, start = 1, stop = 2)
# [1] "79" "84" "89"
```

Answer (score 40):

Here's a `stringr` solution:

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "^.{2}")
```

Returns first 2 characters of `x`

Comment: Or: stringr::str_sub(x, start = 1, end=2)

Comment: Hi, what if i want only 2 digits after the asterisk symbol? for example A*42:09 or ABD*24:87.

Comment: You probably need an anchor, something like ""(?<=\\*){2}"

Answer (score 5):

Use `gsub`...

```
x <- c("75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85 to 89") 

gsub(" .*$", "", x) # Replace the rest of the string after 1st space with  nothing
[1] "75" "80" "85"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @user5249203, but extracts a number/group, instead of removing everything after the space.  In this case, the values can be any number of consecutive digits.

```r
x <- c("75 to 79", "80 to 84", "85 to 89")

sub("^(\\d+) to \\d+"$, "\\1", x)
# [1] "75" "80" "85"
```

If you wanted to extract the lower & upper bound in one call, [rematch2](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rematch2) concise places each "named group" into its own tibble column.

```r
rematch2::re_match(x, "^(?<lower>\\d+) to (?<upper>\\d+)$")
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   lower upper .text    .match  
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>   
# 1 75    79    75 to 79 75 to 79
# 2 80    84    80 to 84 80 to 84
# 3 85    89    85 to 89 85 to 89
```