# R: Get cells which contains four numbers in a row and get this numbers

Tags: r, split

I'm programming in R and I have a dataset like this:

```
Date 
"mrt 2015"
"2012-06-22"
"2012 in Munchen"
"1998?"
"02-2012"
"02-01-1990"
..
```

How do I retrieve the four numeric values in a row (2015, 2012, 2012, 1998, ..)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to extract the first 2 Characters in a string by a function in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750535/how-to-extract-the-first-2-characters-in-a-string-by-a-function-in-r)

Comment: I didn't see I posted the example dataset with structure.. The real dataset doesn't have any structure, I will edit my post now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to capture the group of 4 numbers anywhere in your string:

```
sub(".*(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", your_strings)
#[1] "2015" "2012" "2012" "1998" "2012" "1990"
```

**Explanation:** `.*` means anything 0 or more times, then you put what you want to capture in between bracket (so 4 digits: `\\d{4}`) then again, anything 0 or more times (`.*`).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to get the numbers if they occur at the beginning of the string or else return NA

```
library(stringr)
as.integer(str_extract(df1$Date, "^\\d{4}"))
#[1] 2015 2012 2012 1998
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's edited dataset, if the 4 digit number occurs anywhere in the string, we remove the `^` which implies beginning of string and use only the pattern `\\d{4}` i.e. 4 digit number

```
as.integer(str_extract(df1$Date, "\\d{4}"))
#[1] 2015 2012 2012 1998 2012 1990
```

Note that this is very specific i.e. if there is an element that doesn't have the pattern, it returns `NA`

```
as.integer(str_extract(c('mrt 2015', 'mr5', '201-01', '02-01-1990', '2012'), '\\d{4}'))
#[1] 2015   NA   NA 1990 2012
```

---

Or a `base R` option is `regmatches/regexpr`

```
as.integer(regmatches(df1$Date, regexpr("\\d{4}", df1$Date)))
#[1] 2015 2012 2012 1998 2012 1990
```

Comment: Oh I didn't see I posted the example dataset with structure.. The real dataset doesn't have any structure, I will edit my post now

Comment: @Ziezo If that is the case, remove the `^` I updated the post