# Extract first N digits from a string

Tags: r

I want to extract just FIRST TWO DIGITS from some strings.
Suppose the data is :

```
ABC Conference Room Monitor - Z5580J    
ABC 19 Monitor    
ABC 24 Monitor for Video-Conferencing
ABC UltraSharp 24 Monitor -QU2482Z
```

Output desired:

```
55
19
24
24
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the first 2 Characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750535/extract-the-first-2-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: No, it is not a dupe of [Extract the first 2 Characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750535). Digits are not any chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using regex `\\D` to match non-digit characters and `\\d{2}` to match first two digits.

```
as.numeric(sub("\\D*(\\d{2}).*", "\\1", INPUT))
# [1] 55 19 24 24
```

data:

```
INPUT <- c("ABC Conference Room Monitor - Z5580J",
           "ABC 19 Monitor",
           "ABC 24 Monitor for Video-Conferencing",
           "ABC UltraSharp 24 Monitor -QU2482Z")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
strings <- c('ABC Conference Room Monitor - Z5580J','ABC 19 Monitor','ABC 24 Monitor for Video-Conferencing','ABC UltraSharp 24 Monitor -QU2482Z')
x <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", strings))
as.numeric(substring(as.character(x*100), 1, 2))

[1] 55 19 24 24
```

Comment: why not just  `as.numeric(substr(gsub("\\D", "", strings),1,2))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Package `stringr` perhaps allows for the cleanest solution:

```
stringr::str_extract(string, "\\d{2}")
 "55" "19" "24" "24"
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution with `stringr` is:

```
library(stringr)
string <- str_extract_all("ABC Conference Room Monitor - Z5580J","\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?")[[1]]
# "\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?" is the regex, extracts only numbers
as.numeric(substr(string , 1,2)) # this selects the first two elements
#as.numeric is optional
```