# Extract up to two more digits

Tags: r, regex

This may be a very simple question but I have not much experience with regex expressions. This [page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) is a good source of regex expressions but could not figure out how to include them into my following code:

```
data %>% filter(grepl("^A01H1", icl))
```

**Question**

I would like to extract the values in one column of my `data` frame starting with this `A01H1` up to 2 more digits, for example `A01H100, A01H140, A01H110`. I could not find a solution despite my few attempts:

**Attempts**

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750535/extract-the-first-2-characters-in-a-string) from which I used `^A01H1[0-9].{2}` to select up tot two more digits.

I tried with adding any character `^A01H1[0-9][0-9][x-y]` to stop after two digits.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: `^A01H1.*?\d{2}` or `^A01H1\d{1,2}` or `^A01H1\d{1,2}(?!\d)`? Do you expect any text between `A01H1` and two digits? Do you expect any text after the 2 digits?

Comment: `"^A01H1\\d{1,2}$"`? Please provide a short example with values that should be matched and should not be matched ;)

Comment: this `"^A01H1\\d{1,2}$"` works very well, could you explain this further?? unfortunately these `^A01H1.*?\d{2} `or `^A01H1\d{1,2}` or `^A01H1\d{1,2}(?!\d)` do not work.

Comment: Did you try them properly? `grepl("^A01H1\\d{1,2}(?!\\d)", icl, perl=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"^A01H1\\d{1,2}$"`. 
The first part (`"^A01H1"`), you figured out yourself, so what are we doing in the second part (`"\\d{1,2}$"`)?

- `\d` includes all digits and is equivalent to `[0-9]`, since we are working in R you need to escape `\` and thus we use `\\d`
- `{1,2}` indicates we want to have 1 or 2 matches of `\\d`
- `$` specifies the end of the string, so nothing should come afterwards and this prevents to match more than 2 digits

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you want to match a part of a string that starts with `A01H1`, then contains 1 or 2 digits and then is not followed with any digit.

You may use

```
^A01H1\d{1,2}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D72Rx3/1). **If there can be no text after two digits at all, replace  `(?!\d)` with `$`.**

**Details**

- `^` - start of strinmg
- `A01H1` - literal string
- `\d{1,2}`  - one to two digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the right
- `$` - end of string

In R, you could use it like

```
grepl("^A01H1\\d{1,2}(?!\\d)", icl, perl=TRUE)
```

Or, with the string end anchor,

```
grepl("^A01H1\\d{1,2}$", icl)
```

Note the `perl=TRUE` is only necessary when using PCRE specific syntax like `(?!\d)`, a negative lookahead.